# Pass the parameter Object

Tags: java

I have this test method:

```
public void load(Class<? extends Object> className, XXXX)
{
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(className);
  List<Object> list = criteria.list();

  for (Object item : list)
  {
    list.add(new Object(item.getId, item.getCode); /* Object doesn't know getId */
  }
}
```

How to replace XXXX in load method to call it using concrete `Object`? Something like:

```
load(Foo.class, testObject)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every generic type must extend Object, so this is sufficient:

```
public <T> void load(Class<T> className, T object)
{
    // snip...
}
```

Comment: Not sure what library `Criteria` comes from, though... perhaps you're looking for the Criteria API? http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm able to pass instance of class Object (e.g. User user). But is it possible to pass Object class? To tell which kind of object will be used? For example: `list.add(new Object(item.getId, item.getCode);` to do the same work as `list.add(new User(item.getId, item.getCode);`

Comment: What you are asking does not make sense. In order to construct an instance, you need to know which concrete class to instantiate. It sounds like you are trying to write code which is too generic.

Comment: Jj, I've tried to reduce several very similar methods, but it probably will not to be possible :-) In any case, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
public <X> void load(Class<X extends Object> className, X object)
```

I think this is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
public <T extends Base> void load(T object){
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(object.class);
    List<T> list = criteria.list();

    for (T item : list)
    {
        System.out.println(item.getId)); /* Object doesn't know getId */
    }
}
```

Parameterizing the the void allows you to use generics. Since you are looking for an instance of T, and T is not defined yet, when you pass an object into load(T object) it will automatically set T to whatever class the object is. It auto parametrizes the void.

Generics are extremely useful. For an example, it's used in the List and Set classes as well as Map. However they come with their own risks. If you don't put the T extends Base or some class then you'll get compilation errors because java can not be sure that the class passed will have getId. Setting up a class that it must inherit will ensure that the object must know that method.

replace Base with the base class that knows "getId" and make all other classes you could even end up passing into load() extend that class. Notice no need to pass a Class into the load() because we will just use the class of the object instead, which has the same effect.